# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series" when trying to filter Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

daily_df = pd.read_csv (r'Data\\CSV\daily.csv')
sixtymin_df = pd.read_csv (r'Data\\CSV\sixtymin.csv')
thirtymin_df = pd.read_csv (r'Data\\CSV\\thirtymin.csv')
fivemin_df = pd.read_csv (r'Data\\CSV\\fivemin.csv')
merged_df = [daily_df, sixtymin_df, thirtymin_df, fivemin_df]


condition1_data = merged_df[(merged_df[0]['change'] > 2) & (merged_df[0]['high'] > 4) ]
print(condition1_data)
```

When I try to print condition1_data, I receive the error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series".

When I run each condition individually, the data returns and this is the end of what the terminal shows:

```
3774    False
3775    False
3776    False
3777    False
3778    False
3779    False
3780    False
3781    False
3782    False
3783    False
```

and

```
3771    False
3772    False
3773    False
3774    False
3775    False
3776    False
3777    False
3778    False
3779    False
3780    False
3781    False
3782    False
3783    False
```

Individually each conditions seems to be working when called, however, when combined in an attempt to filter the list, I receive that error. When I remove line 12:

```
merged_df = [daily_df, sixtymin_df, thirtymin_df, fivemin_df]
```

And just use either daily_df, sixtymin_df, thirtymin_df, or fivemin_df, the condition statement seems to work fine. I am trying to get them all into one list as it seems the most straightforward way to access the various values within them. I am new to Python so could be easily miss easier alternatives.

Comment: `merged_df = [daily_df, sixtymin_df, thirtymin_df, fivemin_df]` does not merge your DFs.  It only creates a list of your DFs.  Look at `pd.concat()` for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post what the merged_df looks like. Also, that is not the correct way to merge multiple dataframes. I would suggest you to read this up before doing any merges: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html